# Build RPM for Linux CentOS on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, maven, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build an RPM using the RPM Maven Plugin on Windows for deployment on a Linux machine.

> OS of machine that's building RPM: Windows 7 Enterprise, Cygwin 2.5.1
>
> OS of VM installing RPM: CentOS 7

I've run the mvn clean install command and the build is successful.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 48.273s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Apr 24 21:08:51 BST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/157M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I scp this over to the server and run `yum install -y Core1337-1.0-1.noarch.rpm`

I get the following error:

```
Transaction check error:   package Core1337-1.0-1.noarch is
 intended for a different operating system
```

The following is the XML snipped from the Pom.XML file for the Plugin.

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>Core1337</artifactId>
    <packaging>rpm</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Core Libz</name>

    <properties>
        <targetOS>i386-linux</targetOS>
        <rpm-base>opt</rpm-base>
        <rpm-path>app</rpm-path>
        <base-dir>core</base-dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <license>GPL (c) 2005, SWWDC</license>
                <distribution>eSQuireDistro</distribution>
                <group>eSQuireDevel</group>
                <requires>
                    <require>at</require>
                    <require>wget</require>
                    <require>tree</require>
                    <require>cronie</require>
                    <require>openssh-server</require>
                </requires>
                <mappings>
                    <mapping>
                        <directory>/${rpm-base}/${rpm-path}/${base-dir}/python</directory>
                        <filemode>744</filemode>
                        <username>root</username>
                        <groupname>root</groupname>
                        <configuration>false</configuration>
                        <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                        <recurseDirectories>true</recurseDirectories>
                        <dependency />
                        <sources>
                            <source>
                                <location>src/main/python</location>
                            </source>
                        </sources>
                    </mapping>
                    <mapping>
                        <directory>/${rpm-base}/${rpm-path}/${base-dir}/scripts</directory>
                        <filemode>744</filemode>
                        <username>root</username>
                        <groupname>root</groupname>
                        <configuration>false</configuration>
                        <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                        <recurseDirectories>true</recurseDirectories>
                        <dependency />
                        <sources>
                            <source>
                                <location>src/main/scripts</location>
                            </source>
                        </sources>
                    </mapping>
                </mappings>
                <preinstallScriptlet>
                    <script>/bin/logger "installing"</script>
                </preinstallScriptlet>
                <postinstallScriptlet>
                    <script>/bin/logger "uninstalling"</script>
                </postinstallScriptlet>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

This is the generated SPEC file:

```
%define __jar_repack 0
Name: Core1337
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
Summary: Core Libz
License: GPL (c) 2005, SWWDC
Distribution: eSQuireDistro
Group: eSQuireDevel
Requires: at
Requires: wget
Requires: tree
Requires: cronie
Requires: openssh-server
autoprov: yes
autoreq: yes
BuildArch: noarch
BuildRoot: /cygdrive/C/Users/ala/workspace/alan/Core/target/rpm/Core1337/buildroot

%description

%install

if [ -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT ];
then
  mv /cygdrive/C/Users/ala/workspace/alan/Core/target/rpm/Core1337/tmp-buildroot/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
else
  mv /cygdrive/C/Users/ala/workspace/alan/Core/target/rpm/Core1337/tmp-buildroot $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
fi

%files

%attr(744,root,root)  "/opt/esquire/core/python/"
%attr(744,root,root)  "/opt/esquire/core/scripts/"

%pre
/bin/logger "installing"

%post
/bin/logger "uninstalling"
```

How can I configure the plugin to build an RPM with the linux header? Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: the line "<targetOS>i386-linux</targetOS>" in your pom.xml is very suspect...

Comment: http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/ident-params.html#targetOS this is all I can find but I cant get any information on the values that need to be inserted

Comment: I don't know if you have to fill it in yourself. "By default, this will be populated to the System property os.name.". I use rpmbuild on linux and I never fill it in myself... UNLESS you want to produce "noarch"; in that case you fill in "noarch"

Comment: Ya, I'm trying to build it on Windows using Cygwin, I may have to just use the CentOS machine. Can you explain 'noarch' ? Does this mean it's a generic, not intended for any architecture? I still get the same error with this type of RPM. - I'm just used to building on windows and drag + dropping it onto the server.

Comment: yes noarch means for any archictecture; scripts for example...

Comment: building on windows and deploying on centos might be complicated... no experience with that. I try to build my rpm on the same OS on which it will be deployed.

Comment: Cheers - it worked if I cloned it to the CentOS machine and built it there -- I prefer to develop with GUI on Windows and deploy then on CentOS server which is why I was trying to mix the platforms. I'll look into it and let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that as the answer to your question then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building RPMS on windows for deployment on linux machines might be complicated. I would suggest building the RPMS on the same OS on which it will be deployed.

Comment: This is not an actual answer

Answer (score 1):

Using the rpmbuild command directly, the target OS can be overridden with the `--target` option.

```
rpmbuild -bb hello.spec --target x86_64-linux
```

To verify:

```
rpm -qp --qf '%{os}\n' hello-1-1.x86_64.rpm 
linux
```